# Почему во многопоточных приложениях нужно создавать n+1 рабочих потоков?

Tags: многопоточность

Где `n` - количество физических ядер. Не раз уже встречаю это правило, но никак не могу понять зачем так делать и всегда ли оно эффективнее создания `n` потоков.

Comment: Я такое правило не припоминаю, можете дать источник данной информации?

Comment: @Artem, первый раз услышал в [курсе](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-_cKNuVAYAWpJ_t_8YLSvkoxA9GsQYVQ) по параллельному программированию.  А только что пытался скомпилировать одну [библиотеку](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed) и опять встетил строчку "make [-j CPU_CORES+1] install"

Comment: Таки общая рекомендация скорее `n` потоков. Другое дело, что обычно ещё 1 поток дожидается этих самых `n`, есть в это время не просит и потому не вынуждает систему постоянно переключаться.

Comment: Возможно о jobs в  make стоит почитать [тут](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/jobserver-implementation/) (кстати, там пишут, что в реализации jobserver **не используют** потоки (threads))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> но никак не могу понять зачем так делать

Как правило, программы "общего назначения", кроме, собственно, расчетов выполняют операции ввода-вывода (диск, сеть, прочие устройства). На время ожидания медленных операций ядро неплохо бы загрузить полезной работой. Поэтому добавляют `+1`. Почему `+1` а не более? Сейчас не найду - но помню точно, видел бэйнчмарки для `make -jN`. Практически везде выигрывала комбинация `+1`. Таким образом, устоявшаяся практика - имеет чисто экспериментальную аргументацию.

> и всегда ли оно эффективнее создания n потоков

Не всегда. Если процессы заняты исключительно пересчетами, и доля I/O-операций ничтожно мала - добавление "дополнительного" потока суммарной скорости не прибавит. Более того, возможно скорость незначительно упадет.

Answer (score 9):

Насколько мне известно, такая рекомендация возникла из соображений максимальной утилизации вычислительной мощности. Предполагается, что поток может выполнять какие-либо операции ввода-вывода (диск, сеть, память), требующие большого времени ожидания, в течении которого поток не загружает ядро процессора на 100%. Поэтому создаётся дополнительный `n+1`-й поток, который в это время и использует "простаивающие" мощности.

P.S. Рекомендация не моя и спорить по её поводу я не буду. ;-)

Comment: Плюсанул) Ищи бэйнчмарки! Они о многом говорят. Но есть ну очень скромное подозрение, что `CPU+1` не совсем адекватно! 2+1 = худо-бедно, 4+1=нормуль, 8+1=шикарно ... а 16+2??? ИМХО, не-а!!! Ни разу!!! 16+[3...4] (не факт что 4 лучше, только по тому что 4+1). Самое главное!!! Не забываем следить за памятью! Если начинает юзаться своп - все свои бэйнчмарки отдайте на отопление детских садиков и домов престарелых.

Answer (score 6):

Рекомендация N+1 применима только для систем, которые обрабатывают поток неравномерных задач, с частыми, но короткими прерываниями на IO. Типичный пример - `make -jN`, который тут уже упоминали. В нем "дополнительный" поток позволяет заполнить простои CPU, вызванные IO.

Для систем, обрабатывающих заведомо одинаковые длинные задачи, CPU-bound, без IO - выгоднее выставление количества задач в N + использование affinity - привязки потока к конкретному ядру.

Самый верный способ узнать, сколько потоков лучше использовать для конкретной задачи - взять и померять.